# Sequence defined by $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{a_n}$ is increasing and $a_n<3$ for all $n$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to show that the Sequence defined by $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=3-\frac{1}{a_n}$ is increasing and $a_n<3$ for all $n$.

I just kind of feel lost when it comes to "showing" a sequence will be increasing, decreasing, or monatomic. Any tips on going about this? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try looking at the first few elements of the sequence to get a feeling how the sequence "acts", and then prove by induction.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1} -  a_n = \dfrac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{a_na_{n-1}}$.

Use this to prove that your sequence is increasing. Then the fact that $a_n<3$ follows immediately, because all the terms are positive.

Comment: @mrnovice Nope, look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(n%2B1)%3D3-1%2Fg(n),+g(1)%3D1)

Comment: It was directed to mrnovice.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a stronger statement, which implies the posted one since $1 \gt \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\,$, $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\lt 3\,$.

> If $\,a_1 \in (\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})\,$ then the sequence is increasing and $\,a_n \in (\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})\,$ for $\forall n \ge 1\,$.

Note that $x_{1,2}=\cfrac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ are the roots of the quadratic $P(x)=x^2-3x+1\,$.

**1.** $\;\;a_n \gt \cfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ $\implies$ $\quad a_{n+1}=3 - \cfrac{1}{a_n} > 3 - \cfrac{2}{3-\sqrt{5}}=3 - \cfrac{2(3+\sqrt{5})}{3^2-5}=3-\cfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2} =  \cfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

**2.**   Similarly, $a_n \lt \cfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ $\implies$ $a_{n+1} \lt \cfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

**3.** $\;\;a_{n+1}-a_n = 3-\cfrac{1}{a_n}-a_n=-\cfrac{a_n^2-3a_n+1}{a_n} \gt 0\,$ because $\,P(x) \lt 0$ for $x \in (x_1,x_2)\,$.

**1.** and **2.** prove that $a_{n+1} \in (\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})\,$, and **3.** proves that $a_{n+1} \gt a_n\,$.